# How to call a hook conditionally without getting the "rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I currently have a screen where I call:

`const currentBusiness = useSelector(state => state.business.ownerBusiness)`

However, not all users own a business, so sometimes useSelector will not find a business meaning currentBusiness would be `false` and sometimes it will be `true` (depending on the logged in user).

Underneath this hook call, I have another hook where I call

`const employeeArray = useSelector(state => state.employees.availableEmployees.filter(employee => employee.businessId === currentBusiness.Id));`

The second useSelector relies on the first useSelector actually returning something because it uses currentBusiness.Id in the filter method.

**I have two questions:**

1. if I put the second `useSelector` in an `if` statement with the condition that `currentBusiness === true`, how do I use the `employeeArray` outside of the `if` statement, because my VSCode shows me that once it is nested in the `if` statement I can only call it in there.
2. In the case that I solve my first question, how do I prevent getting the error "rendered more hooks than during the previous render", because if currentBusiness is false I would not be executing the `useSelector` in the `if` statement (i will be rendering a certain screen) however when it is true, I will be executing that one extra hook which causes the error. (I will be rendering a different screen listing all the current employees).

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You simply can not call hooks conditionally so the answer to your first question is just: You can't. 
The reason why your code doesn't work is probably because the design of your custom hook is incorrect or violates more rules of react hooks, so a complete code example is needed here.